# Cloud Foundry in Ubuntu OpenStack

Tags: cloud, openstack

I have my final year project titled *"E-WASTE Management System Using Cloud Foundry"*.

The task is to :

1. Install and Deploy Cloud Foundry in Ubuntu OpenStack.
2. Design, develop and run E-Waste Management System.
3. Evaluate the application in terms of performance and capacity.

I don't know how to install and deploy Cloud Foundry on Ubuntu OpenStack. Are there any methods or examples to use as reference?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use bosh and the openstack connector : http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/openstack/

You can also use the chef recipes (not supported by Pivotal) with knife tool:  https://github.com/andreacampi

Comment: Additionally, you can get help with bosh in the bosh Google Group https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/bosh-users

Comment: The first url http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/openstack/  is redirecting to an unhelpful page.  I don't see the same page at docs.cloudfroundry.org.  Do you have a good update?